# Clearing instruments CPU profiling

Tags: ios, instruments

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but is there a way in Instruments to clear the CPU profile data without restarting the App?

I have an iOS game I'm trying to profile just to core game screen, but I have to go though several other screens to get to that point and by that time I have a ton of profiling data I don't care about and it's skewing the results of that I'm trying to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to launch another Instruments run without restarting the app, but you can hide the profiling data you don't care about by using the Inspection Range buttons in the toolbar. Above the graphs in the trace window is a timeline. Click the timeline where the interesting profiling data begins, and click the left Inspection Range button. The graph will be highlighted where you set the inspection range, and the statistics in the detail view will update to show the statistics for the inspection range you set.

If you need to further refine the inspection range, click a second point in the timeline and click the right Inspection Range button. Clicking the middle Inspection Range button clears the inspection range you set.